# Finding dates in a single list of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data as such:

```
Transactions
Source
PTS Collected/Spent
23/02/2015 08:07
Unleaded Premium
qty: 41
SHELL ABCDE
41 points
12/02/2015 17:44

31/12/2014 23:59
Central points -
SHELL
50 points
19/12/2014 18:43
Unleaded Premium
qty: 20
SHELL ABCDE
20 points
Transactions
Source
PTS Collected/Spent
16/12/2014 18:13
```

Unfortunately the data is inconsistent in how many rows it is showing per transaction.

e.g. data for 23/02 has data + 5 lines of info
data for central points has date + 3 lines.

I am trying to make 1 list with all the dates in it and then I can pull the rest of the data from that date and offset it. However, I dont know how to get a single list which will show every date which appears in my data.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using `VBA` it is pretty simple using `IsDate`:

```
Sub ExtractDates()

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim c As Range, rng as Range

'Start row to input dates
iRow = 1

'Target range
Set rng = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1:A25")

'Loop through target range and add any dates to Column C
For Each c In rng 
    If IsDate(c.Value) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Cells(iRow, "C").Value = c.Value
        iRow  = iRow + 1
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```